# Falsified voting in Stackoverflow

Tags: support

My stackoverflow account is suspended due to falsified voting.But I know i m very loyal and most of time I gave answer what my Sir has thought rather than googling.What vote i got is not by me but by stackoverflow users then how they can see it is wrong voting.

After reading so many docs and learning and being loyal I got information that your account is suspended.Really I am feeling insulted for being loyal.

Why my account is suspended?

Comment: The moderator message that you have received tells you why.

Comment: Just curious, @Oded: can moderators tell if such message was shown (hence probably: was read)?

Comment: @Arjan - Yes, we can. With a timestamp...

Comment: @Oded: What concerns my here is that this user got 930 rep until being noticed. Maybe the algorithm needs a little improvment?

Comment: @juergend I think the intent is to be really careful with the automated stuff, so that false positives don't happen (often). Beyond that, instances like this have ways of bubbling up at some point, and there are some tools we (mods) can use occasionally to sort of troll for patterns.

Comment: @juergend Vote fraud gets much easier to prove if there is a large amount of votes, so making the tools more sensitive would not necessarily be a good idea. Moderators also tend to just observe for a while when they encounter a possible vote fraud case that is still ambiguous.

Answer (score 14):

From what I can see, with my non-mod powers, a user upvoted 93 of your answers serially and got deleted.

I'm not certain, because I'm not a mod; a mod would have all the details. From what I see, though, it looks like you made an account and upvoted all of your answers with it.

Don't do that.

After the suspension is over, you will get all your (legitimate) rep back. (You won't get the 930 rep from the serial voting, of course.)

Comment: @Shoaib: Based on your [reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2396624/shoaib-chikate?tab=reputation), a single user account upvoted your answers *ninety three times.*  We don't allow that here.  Read your suspension letter.

Comment: Then after completion of my suspension do i will get my reputations back.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate - The **legitimate** reputation will be restored.

Comment: That's dedication!

Comment: So, does this mean I can make a fake account upvote @doorknobs questions 90 times and get him suspended?

Comment: @Pinocchio only if you share his IP address

Comment: Today I gave best answer and got pissed off...And dont know who that user was who voted me 93 times...But more than his votes.I have my own

Comment: @JanDvorak I gathered that would be the evidence they had, but that wasn't  mentioned.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate the moderator who suspended you apparently knew it was you who upvoted you.

Comment: Suppose my rep are 1930 then after suspension period do I will get 1930-930=1000 rep back

Comment: My guess is the accounts shared the same IP.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate You are proving your guiltiness with such reputation concern

Comment: @Pinocchio no need for a proof. I trust the mods here.

Comment: I loved that my answer was upvoted by 35 people and it helped others to learn...nothing more

Comment: @ShoaibChikate Once your suspension is over, you'll have the rep back that was determined to be legitimate.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate that's not what you got suspended for, however.

Comment: Can we know who has upvoted us as we have in FB?

Comment: @ShoaibChikate no. Votes are anonymous on purpose.

Comment: And before you ask "then how can they know there is something suspicious", the system does maintain who voted on what. Moderators get an indication of this when something is not as it should be (they can't see the actual voting data).

Comment: @ShoaibChikate moderators are very careful before suspending anyone, so they would not do it if they didn't have proof.  For your own privacy, those details are not made public (except to other mods and SE employees).  As several people have mentioned, you would have received a letter notifying you of the suspension and the details of why would have been in that letter.  If you feel the allegations are not legitimate, you should contact the SE team.

Comment: My suspension is over but still i didn't legitimate reputation

Comment: Got my rep back .Thanks